# ES6 Parse Cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I currently have a very simple file going:

```
var {
    Object,
    File,
    Relation,
    Cloud,
} = Parse

final class Job extends Object {
    constructor(params) {
        super("Job")
        this.descriptionText = params.descriptionText
        this.completed = false
        this.currentBids = this.relation("currentBids")
        this.bidCount = 0
        this.acceptedBid = false

        const imageFile = new File("imageFile", params.imageBytes);
        imageFile.save()
        this.imageFile = imageFile

        this.jobTitle = params.jobTitle
        this.jobCategory = params.jobCategory
        this.createdBy = params.user
    }
}

Cloud.define("createJob", function(request, response) {
    const job = Job(request.params);
    job.save().then(function() {
        response.success()
    }, function(error) {
        response.error("Error saving job")
    })
})
```

From Parse Docs:

> If you’re already using ES6 in your codebase, good news! From version 1.6.0 onwards, the JavaScript SDK is compatible with ES6 classes. You can subclass Parse.Object with the extends keyword

However, when I run `parse deploy`, I'm getting:

`Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in Job.js:1 at main.js:1:1`

I'm pretty new to JavaScript in general so the above code might be erroneous. But I don't see why the it would error in right from the start on the destructuring syntax.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a `final` keyword. And, there's no way to prevent an object from being used as the prototype for another object. Being able to do so would disable creating instances at all with prototypal inheritance.

Comment: this looks dangerous ... you're overwriting (or attempting to) javascript `Object`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!